# Infer enum from object property in typescript with generics

Tags: typescript, generics, enums, typescript-generics

I have a scenario where I want to validate commands from their schema id and return typed validation results. For this, I need to be able to infer the enum value of the schema id.

I know I can use generics for this, like `TSchemaId extends SchemaId`, and it works. However, when I try to infer it from inside an object, it doesn't behave as I thought it would.

Here's what I have

```js
enum SchemaId {
  SCHEMA_1 = 'SCHEMA_1',
  SCHEMA_2 = 'SCHEMA_2',
}

function inferSchemaId<TSchemaId extends SchemaId> (schemaId: TSchemaId): TSchemaId {
  return schemaId
}

function inferObjectSchemaId<
    TSchemaId extends SchemaId,
    TObjectWithSchemaId extends { schemaId: TSchemaId },
> (objectWithSchemaId: TObjectWithSchemaId): TSchemaId {
  return objectWithSchemaId.schemaId
}

const si1 = inferSchemaId(SchemaId.SCHEMA_1)                     // SchemaId.SCHEMA_1
const si2 = inferObjectSchemaId({ schemaId: SchemaId.SCHEMA_1 }) // SchemaId
```

As you can see above, `si1` is correctly narrowed to `SchemaId.SCHEMA_1`, but `si2` cannot be narrowed down.

Why is it the case? What am I missing?

Comment: TypeScript doesn't use constraints as inference sites; so `TSch` cannot be inferred form anything (you are apparently hoping `TObj extends {schemaId: TSch}` will cause the latter to be inferred, but it doesn't happen).  You should probably refactor to have exactly one generic type and have it directly mentioned in the parameter types.  You can recover `TSch` from `TObj`, or you could just use `TSch`; both approaches are shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/wgoDlw). Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz Yes it answers my question! "TypeScript doesn't use constraints as inference sites" is exactly the answer I was looking for, and now it makes sense why the syntax behaves like it does!

Comment: I'll write up an answer when I get a chance. Probably tomorrow because it is near my bedtime now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you're having is that the [generic constraint](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) `ObjectWithSchemaId extends { schemaId: TSchemaId }` is not an *inference site* for the `TSchemaId` type parameter.  Such functionality was suggested at [microsoft/TypeScript#7234](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7234) but it was never implemented, since you can usually get the desired behavior in other ways.  That means there's nowhere at all for TypeScript to infer `TSchemaId` from, so it falls back to *its* constraint of `SchemaId`, and everything follows from that.

---

You'll need to refactor if you want to change how it works.  You could either just accept `TObjectWithSchemaId` and compute `TSchemaId` from it as an [indexed access type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html)

```
function inferObjectSchemaId<
  TObjectWithSchemaId extends { schemaId: SchemaId },
>(objectWithSchemaId: TObjectWithSchemaId): TObjectWithSchemaId["schemaId"] {
  return objectWithSchemaId.schemaId
}
```

or just accept `TSchemaId` and compute an appropriate type for `objectWithSchemaId` form it:

```
function inferObjectSchemaId<
  TSchemaId extends SchemaId,
>(objectWithSchemaId: { schemaId: TSchemaId, [k: string]: any }): TSchemaId {
  return objectWithSchemaId.schemaId
}
```

or take some other approach that doesn't involve trying to infer from constraints.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAygxgC2BAhgSQCZQN4CgqwDCAEgKICyAggPoCMUAvFAOQwkU23MA0+RZVagCZGLNgJpCeuAL65cAMzAg4AFwCWAexBR1IBcABO8JKkwAeAConk6LMAAeq0BgDOsRLcwA+ABSvPMwwALihrQLsASlDw0zscPkNgVTBDHQC4zFl5EBQIYFcABxQ4YCgAeRAyvAIlFQ1tXX0jcoAjACtgNRsg8z4CSzbOtQB1dVUEHvjHZxA3HCgMrxCPTKwZXgI-TQ6u1TGJqcwYob2DyYjMaLDT0fGLtYBtACIloOeAXQSCAiSUtKgO2G+3uRwwADo3nY+HI+HBtK5VIt1PQmHoDMZLhhfGDweIOHRIj9iSTST8APTk1bLPHsQS0OEIpGudQiNHNQy3VRg3zYRZY0K4-H0qAyImU6lBWkSOjZXC5fJFEplSwAd003ygdTUWh06Jau26WL6xNiyygMxc7jBmyg20NIMOAoWUOOYRtUEeAGtQojDHoAOYfUIoEAAT1F1zNQU1v2SqR0QLOoKxkKxMPkBHhIERyNRTQxPKFdM4RLJ5ZJEuLMoZWaZyLZBYNwJ5fNdK2rBPoYqgVdTws48hkQA)

Answer (score 0):

It is strange to return not only the type (SchemaId) but also to infer the exact value. I have made a case where it works:

```js
enum SchemaId {
  SCHEMA_1 = 'SCHEMA_1',
  SCHEMA_2 = 'SCHEMA_2',
}

function inferSchemaId<TSchemaId extends SchemaId> (schemaId: TSchemaId): TSchemaId {
  return schemaId
}

type ObjectWithSchemaId<T extends SchemaId> = { schemaId: T }

type InferSchemaIdFromObj<S> = S extends ObjectWithSchemaId<infer T>? T : never;

function inferObjectSchemaId<
    TObjectWithSchemaId extends ObjectWithSchemaId<SchemaId>,
> (objectWithSchemaId: TObjectWithSchemaId): InferSchemaIdFromObj<TObjectWithSchemaId> {
  return objectWithSchemaId.schemaId as InferSchemaIdFromObj<TObjectWithSchemaId>
}

const si1 = inferSchemaId(SchemaId.SCHEMA_1)                     // SchemaId.SCHEMA_1
const si2 = inferObjectSchemaId({ schemaId: SchemaId.SCHEMA_1 }) // SchemaId.SCHEMA_1
```

[Typescript playground link](https://tsplay.dev/w1GE8m)

Comment: The fact that you have to cast shows that Typescript doesn't correctly map the enum value. I'm trying to understand why the syntax in `inferObjectSchemaId` does not behave similarly to the one in `inferSchemaId`

Comment: I do cast, but it correctly infwrs the specific enum value. It is strange to infer constants.